# What does Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing event with NULL SID mean?

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-event-log

On a Windows Server 2012 machine, in Event Viewer, there was some unusual behaviour on a system, a service was stopping and I was unsure if it "stopped itself" or was forced to stop by a user action.  So I went to `Windows logs | Security` area in `eventvwr.msc` and I see no logons of any ordinary users, but I do see a pattern repeating of the following kind:

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Task Category: Logon
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Description:   An account was successfully logged on.
Subject:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0
Logon Type:         3
Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Logon GUID:     {a7...}
LogonProcessName: Kerberos
```

I am assuming that this means that a service is bootstrapping into the SYSTEM context, and that the NULL SID referenced in the event log is only the initial state of some unauthenticated System or Kernel or Service code.  Is my interpretation correct or is this something else?

From the logon process name, I assume this is the Microsoft Kerberos service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local SYSTEM account's are outside the security subsystem.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I think I already knew that.  I was wondering what the significance of a Null SID is. Is a Null SID uniquely identifying that LocalSystem is the service account context or does it have a different meaning?  LocalSystem has a specific SID that is NOT NULL, doesn't it?

Comment: SID's are used by the security system to identify accounts.  So that means any account outside the security subsystem wouldn't have need of a SID when working with local resources.  There's no need for it to request a Token from an authentication source.

Comment: Hmm. So why is there an audit log success entry?

Comment: Because a security event was triggered.

Comment: i don't think that's accurate, the LocalSystem account does have a SID, and it's S-1-5-18 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330). You didn't mention what event id the event is?

Comment: The SID is used in authentication to network resources.  As we're dealing with a local instance of system, there's no need to use the SID.

Answer (score 2):

In Local Context SYSTEM account is a well known SID. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/243330/well-known-security-identifiers-in-windows-operating-systems

But if we are seeing the event on a Domain Controller, something is accessing over the network. LocalSystem Account accesses network resources in context of the machine account, so you should see the SID for the computer account in AD, not NULL. So I'm still not convinced on the explanation that it is SYSTEM account. Does it imply anonymous logon is enabled for the domain?